# Rewrite htaccess directory to behave as a external website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have one website, for example `http://example.com/` and another one `http://example.myeshop.com/`. I want to make accessible URL `http://example.com/eshop` to be same as `http://example.myeshop.com/`, but no redirects. Also when someone use link like `http://example.com/eshop/contact` it would have same effect as `http://example.myeshop.com/contact` and so on. This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /eshop/(.*) http://example.myeshop.com/$1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xhtml text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript text/css
</IfModule>

FileETag none
```

But doesn't seem to be working. Can you help me how to achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is mod-proxy. Enable proxy module on your server and then you can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^eshop/(.*)$ http://example.myeshop.com/$1 [P]
```

This will internally forword all requests of example.com to example.myeshop.com . You will get an internal server error if the proxy module isnt enabled.

Comment: Hello, I think the op wants to start proxying after eshop/ so rule should be like this `RewriteRule ^eshop/(.*)$ http://example.myeshop.com/$1 [P]` or not?

Comment: It doesn't work for me and also get no errors. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to httpd.conf you can use below rules in your httpd.conf file where section for `mod_proxy` is mentioned or might be you have to put in `extra/httpd-ajp.conf`.

```
ProxyPass /eshop/ http://example.myeshop.com/
ProxyPassReverse /eshop/ http://example.myeshop.com/
```

These two lines should be uncommented in your `httpd.conf` file.

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to that file.

Comment: Okay so are you sure that you have mod proxy enabled.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to check it.

Comment: You have to make it confirm by your hosting provider that your `.htaccess` have access to mod_proxy.

Comment: Would it be possible to do that rewrite through DNS?

Comment: Well I tried to add DNS record with type A and put there and IP (from cmd ping www...) but it doesn't work, because subdomain has same IP as main domain.